# Error when submitting app to iTunes: "Application executable is missing a required architecture"

Tags: iphone, xcode4

please i need some help.

I got this message in Organiser when trying to submit my app to iTunes connect: ***"iPhone/iPod Touch; application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6 "***. There is no problem when building for on a iPhone or simulator.

I use xcode 4

Thank for any help:

Comment: Can you tell us more about your project? Do you have any static libraries linked in your workspace?

Answer (score 1):

Check the project build settings "Architectures".  You're likely building with "Optimized armv7" instead of "Standard armv6, armv7".  Your iPhone (3GS or 4) can handle armv7 but I think some of the older devices you may be targeting once you get to iTunes (iPhone 2G/3G, iPod 1G/2G) can't and require armv6.